# In MYSQL, I want to get multiple SUM with multiple condition to do the totals and get the price-milestone

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ezsql

Here is my SQL code. I have selected the price of each row and the milestone of each row and the id to join the tables, but I have only the result of one row.

PHP code to do multiple filters:

```
if($i==0)
{
    if($fc == "projet")
    {
        $filtre_bdd .= "AND p.$fc = '$fv' ";
    }
    else 
    {
        $filtre_bdd .= "AND cible.$fc = '$fv' ";
        $i= $i + 2;
    }
}
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT cible.prix,a.valeur,a.idroute,cible.id,p.id,
    SUM(DISTINCT a.valeur) AS total_avances, /* the milestone sum the unique one */
    SUM(a.valeur) AS total_avance, /* the milestone sum of each row */
    SUM(cible.prix) AS total_prix /* the price sum */
FROM avances AS a,routes AS cible,projets AS p
WHERE a.idroute = cible.id AND p.id = cible.idprojet $filtre_bdd /* the conditions to join the tables and do the filter */
GROUP BY cible.id, a.idroute 
HAVING total_avances <> cible.prix AND cible.prix - total_avances >- 1
```

Now how can I get the totals of the prices and the total of the milestones with all those conditions? The targeted table contains the id of the project and the id of the milestones. We have to do the sum of the milestones for each row and sum of the sums and compare it to the project price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution thank you

```
SELECT SUM(alucard.uu) as total_prix,SUM(alucard.vv) as total_avances FROM(
                                SELECT ultimate.id,SUM(ultimate.prix) as uu,SUM(ultimate.valeur) as vv FROM(
                                    SELECT e.id,e.prix,e.idprojet,e.valeur FROM(
                                        SELECT cible.id,cible.prix,cible.idprojet,a.valeur=4 AS valeur FROM avances AS a
                                            INNER JOIN routes cible ON a.idroute=cible.id 
                                            INNER JOIN projets p ON p.id=cible.idprojet $filtre_bdd 
                                             $date_bdd
                                            GROUP BY cible.id) AS e
                                    UNION 

                                    SELECT cible.id,cible.prix=4,cible.idprojet,SUM(a.valeur) FROM avances as a
                                        INNER JOIN routes cible ON a.idroute=cible.id 
                                        INNER JOIN projets p ON p.id=cible.idprojet $filtre_bdd 
                                        $date_bdd
                                        GROUP BY cible.id) AS ultimate
                                    GROUP BY ultimate.id
                                    HAVING SUM(ultimate.prix)>SUM(ultimate.valeur) ) AS alucard
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following query:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT cible.prix, a.valeur, a.idroute, cible.id, p.id,
SUM(a.valeur) AS total_avances,
SUM(a.valeur) AS total_avance,
SUM(cible.prix) AS total_prix
FROM avances a INNER JOIN routes ciblE ON a.idroute = cible.id
INNER JOIN projets p ON p.id = cible.idprojet
GROUP BY cible.prix, a.valeur, a.idroute, cible.id, p.id,
HAVING total_avances <> cible.prix AND cible.prix - total_avances >- 1
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: thank you, but it didn't work always the same problem

Comment: So can you plz share some schema and some desired output.